# How to use Selenium with chromedriver in apache-airflow in docker?

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, airflow

### Problem

I have a scraper with selenium that I want to run with airflow inside docker. I'm able to create the container and run the related dag of the scraper in airflow. However, whenever the selenium driver gets initiated, I get an error. `('Service' object has no attribute 'process'; 90)`. Which I think can be lead back to the missing chromedriver when I initiate the driver.

### What I tried

I'm currently trying to copy the chromedriver in the Dockerfile so I can use it inside the container. However, this isn't working. How can I use Selenium with chromedriver together with airflow in docker?

### Code

**Error log**

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=scrape_digitec_data/run_id=manual__2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00/task_id=scrape_digitec_data/attempt=1.log
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: scrape_digitec_data.scrape_digitec_data manual__2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: scrape_digitec_data.scrape_digitec_data manual__2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): scrape_digitec_data> on 2023-03-25 13:28:56.191607+00:00
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 90 to run task
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'scrape_digitec_data', 'scrape_digitec_data', 'manual__2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00', '--job-id', '100', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/dag_digitec_scraper.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp9omrthbe']
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 100: Subtask scrape_digitec_data
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {dagbag.py:525} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/***/dags/dag_digitec_scraper.py
[2023-03-25, 13:28:58 UTC] {task_command.py:384} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: scrape_digitec_data.scrape_digitec_data manual__2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00 [running]> on host 48fbc6fdff5d
[2023-03-25, 13:28:59 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1590} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=scrape_digitec_data
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=scrape_digitec_data
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-03-25T13:28:56.191607+00:00
[2023-03-25, 13:28:59 UTC] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/***/utils/context.py:204: AirflowContextDeprecationWarning: Accessing 'execution_date' from the template is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'data_interval_start' or 'logical_date' instead.
  warnings.warn(_create_deprecation_warning(key, self._deprecation_replacements[key]))

[2023-03-25, 13:29:03 UTC] {digitec_deal_of_day_scraper_selenium.py:65} INFO - https://www.digitec.ch/en/product/hp-tilt-pen-styluses-8216103
[2023-03-25, 13:29:03 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:117} INFO - https://www.digitec.ch/en/product/hp-tilt-pen-styluses-8216103
[2023-03-25, 13:29:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1851} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 193, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/dag_digitec_scraper.py", line 10, in _scrape_digitec_data
    day_deals.get_product_info_df()
  File "/opt/airflow/app/product_scraper/adapters/digitec_deal_of_day_scraper_selenium.py", line 32, in get_product_info_df
    product_info_df = self._get_product_info()
  File "/opt/airflow/app/product_scraper/adapters/digitec_deal_of_day_scraper_selenium.py", line 91, in _get_product_info
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 106, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 117, in assert_process_still_running
    return_code = self.process.poll()
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
[2023-03-25, 13:29:05 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=scrape_digitec_data, task_id=scrape_digitec_data, execution_date=20230325T132856, start_date=20230325T132858, end_date=20230325T132905
[2023-03-25, 13:29:05 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:102} ERROR - Failed to execute job 100 for task scrape_digitec_data ('Service' object has no attribute 'process'; 90)
[2023-03-25, 13:29:06 UTC] {local_task_job.py:164} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-03-25, 13:29:06 UTC] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.1-python3.10
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow/app"

COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .
COPY app/product_scraper/adapters/chromedriver .

USER airflow
RUN pip install selenium && \
    pip install bs4 && \
    pip install lxml && \
    pip install selenium-stealth
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  # image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.4.1}
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./app:/opt/airflow/app
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./minio:/data/minio
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  minio:
    image: 'minio/minio:latest'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_MINIO_PORT:-9000}:9000'
      - '${FORWARD_MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT:-9090}:9090'
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: 'root'
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes:
      - ./minio:/data/minio
    command: minio server /data/minio --console-address ":9090"
# volumes:
#    minio:
#        driver: local

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

**driver initiation in scraper script**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# Set user agent
user_agent = 'userMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('-headless')

# Launch the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I have a similar use case for which I'm using pyppeteer and the browser just won't get launched

Comment: Yes, see my answer below. Hope it helps. You have to make sure that an image is available for the scraper framework you want to use. I tried it initially with playwright, but unfortunately I was not able to find a remote driver image for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve it. For this I used a remote Chromedriver.

In the `docker-compose.yaml` I added the following:

```
selenium:
  container_name: remote_chromedriver
  image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium:latest
  ports:
    - 4444:4444
  restart: always
```

This will start a remote chromedriver on port 4444. To access it in the scraper you then have to add the following in you scraper code.

```
remote_webdriver = 'remote_chromedriver'
with webdriver.Remote(f'{remote_webdriver}:4444/wd/hub', options=options) as driver:
  # Scraping part
  pass
```